# Blazor Web Assembly - Page reload (F5) triggers Program.cs Main method: is it correct?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my web assembly Blazor application, a page reload (F5 or NavToUri with forceLoad: true) triggers the Program.cs Main method.
Is it correct, or am i doing something wrong?

I'm asking this because in my situation this causes the loss of the user access token login data

Comment: You should be saving your access token to something more durable, like local storage.  But yes, refreshing the browser will _reload_ the entire page/app (how else would a web page work?)

Comment: It will reload the current Url or the NavigateToUrl i.e. will fetch the page from the source and totally reload the application.   In Web Assembly you will need to store the token in the browser and reload and check it's state. Search the Internet for something like - "Blazor Web Assembly store access token" or something similar to find info, articles and YouTube tutorials.